# Showing an synchronous dialog from a worker task with MVVM gives System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, mahapps.metro

I am trying to display a dialog from a worker task in a synchronous fashion, so that the process can abort or continue the process depending on the user feedback through the dialog.

```
public Task StartBackgroundTask()
{
    var measurementResult = DoQuickPreMeasurement();

    if(measurementSuccessful == false)
    {
        var task = dialogService.ShowMeasurementFailed("Measurement failed because of reason XYZ, continue?!");
        var dialogResult = task.Result;
        if (dialogResult == MessageDialogResult.Negative)
            return Task.CompletedTask; // this ends the background run
    }

    Task.Run(()=>{ LongRunningTask();});
}
```

`StartBackgroundTask()` is called from the UI thread. When I run this, I get the following exception, which I have not been able to resolve:

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll ("The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.")
```

I am using MvvmLight and have tried using various differenct ways of calling the UI dispatcher (using also `DispatcherHelper`), but have not been successfull with this.

This is the reduced code in `DialogService`:

```
public class DialogService
{
    private IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator;
    private ViewModelBase parentViewModel;
    private BaseMetroDialog pleaseCloseLidDialog;
    private BaseMetroDialog openLidPrintingAbortedDialog;
    private BaseMetroDialog shutDownDialog;

    public DialogService(IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator, ViewModelBase parentViewModel)
    {
        this.dialogCoordinator = dialogCoordinator;
        this.parentViewModel = parentViewModel;
    }

    public Task<MessageDialogResult> ShowMeasurementFailed(string message)
    {
        var metroWindow = (MetroWindow)(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        return metroWindow.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
            {
                AffirmativeButtonText = "Continue",
                NegativeButtonText = "Abort"
            };

            return ((MetroWindow)(Application.Current.MainWindow)).ShowMessageAsync(
                "Measurement has finished",
                "Result: " + message + ".\n\nContinue?",
                MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative,
                mySettings);
            //return dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(parentViewModel,
            //    "Measurement has finished",
            //    "Result: " + message + ".\n\nContinue?",
            //    MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative,
            //    mySettings);
        });
    }
}
```

For completeness: `IDialogCoordinator` and `parentViewModel` I am injecting the MahApps implementation (`DialogCoordinator`) using StructureMap as well as the VM for the main window, which works nicely for the other dialogs in the service (which I have omitted in the example above):

```
    this.For<IDialogCoordinator>().Use<DialogCoordinator>().Singleton();

    this.ForConcreteType<DialogService>()
        .Configure
        .Ctor<IDialogCoordinator>("dialogCoordinator").Is(c => c.GetInstance<DialogCoordinator>())
        .Ctor<ViewModelBase>("parentViewModel").Is(c => c.GetInstance<MainWindowDialogParentViewModel>())
        .Singleton();
```

I hope somebody can spot my error or at lease give me ideas on how to debug this.

Comment: I think using the dispatcher is the answer - do you have the code where you attempted to use it?

Comment: @pm_2 Ok. So it appears to be this call that is causing the problem: (MetroWindow)(Application.Current.MainWindow)
After removing it and using the updated method, it is now working.

Comment: @packoman you should self answer with the solution instead of adding it to your original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the call to

```
var metroWindow = (MetroWindow)(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

was the offending call. I have now modified the method ShowMeasurementFailed as follows and it now works:

```
public Task<MessageDialogResult> ShowMeasurementFailed(string message)
{
    var dispatcher = DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher; // get UI dispatcher from MvvmLight
    return dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {
            AffirmativeButtonText = "Continue",
            NegativeButtonText = "Abort"
        };

        return dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(parentViewModel,
            "Measurement has finished",
            "Result: " + message + ".\n\nContinue?",
            MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative,
            mySettings);
    });
}
```

Note that the usage of the dispatcher now works as opposed to my previous attempts. Perhaps I had the offending call above `(MetroWindow)(Application.Current.MainWindow)` still somewhere in my code during testing.